# Detaching terminal of a parent process

Tags: linux, process, tty, linux-namespaces

I'm experimenting with namespaces under Linux so I'm writing a small C program to isolate a Debian Wheezy environment created with debootstrap.

I could successfully start sysv-init and get a login prompt but when I close the isolated environment, either shutting down the system or killing -9 init, the terminal is left in a state where no controlling terminal seems to be attached to the shell. Specifically, if I start sudo it complains that no terminal is present.

I narrowed down the failure point in sudo to the following statement:

```
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY);
```

with error ENXIO (i.e. "No such device or address").

I'm trying to understand why this happens and I have the feeling that's something related to the setsid() system call in init but I couldn't reproduce the exact scenario so I'm unable to provide a proper test case.

What seems really odd to me is that, not only does init (a forked process and thus a child to the shell) detach from the current terminal but also all the hierarchy of processess up to the GUI terminal get detached from the tty as well, which I can't seem to figure out how it happens.

In addition, there is some inconsistencies between different commands:

```
➜  namespaces  tty
/dev/pts/19
➜  namespaces  sudo -s
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
➜  namespaces  ls -l /proc/$$/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 paris paris 64 gen 15 23:24 0 -> /dev/pts/19
lrwx------ 1 paris paris 64 gen 15 23:24 1 -> /dev/pts/19
lrwx------ 1 paris paris 64 gen 15 23:24 10 -> /dev/pts/19
lrwx------ 1 paris paris 64 gen 15 23:24 2 -> /dev/pts/19
➜  namespaces
```

Any clue about this situation is hihgly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Looking at the kernel source code for "/dev/tty" I think the problem is related to the ref counting of the char device on the kernel side. Indeed, in order to redirect "/dev/{console|tty0|tty1}" output to the current pty I bind mounted the controlling terminal of the shell to those device file in the container's mounted dev.

**EDIT**: It seems that in the Linux kernel the error is reported in this step in the "tty_open_current_tty()" function:

```
static struct tty_struct *tty_open_current_tty(dev_t device, struct file *filp)
{
     struct tty_struct *tty;
     int retval;

     if (device != MKDEV(TTYAUX_MAJOR, 0))
         return NULL;

     tty = get_current_tty();
     if (!tty)
         return ERR_PTR(-ENXIO);
     ...
}
```

**EDIT**: It seems that the problem is related to the concept of "stealing" a controlling tty. This can be done under the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability and calling `ioctl()` on the tty file descriptor using TIOCSCTTY as the command and 1 as the parameter (see [tty_ioctl(4)](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl)). I'll try to write a test case to confirm this and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I think your hunch about `setsid()` is probably close. Are there `fork()` invocations close to the `setsid()` invocation? Because a common technique for turning a process into a daemon is to:

- `fork()`
- `setsid()`
- `fork()` again to make sure everything is detached

**Edit**

The source code for the function in question (`init_main`): http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/sysvinit/trunk/src/init.c?root=sysvinit&view=markup

It has the general `fork`, `setsid`, `fork` pattern repeated multiple times. This will ensure detachment from the tty.

Comment: Take a look at the init_main() function.

http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/sysvinit/trunk/src/init.c?root=sysvinit&view=markup

Comment: Yes, it looks like the code flow is: `init_main`, `fork()`, `setsid()`, `spawn()`, `fork()`, `setsid()`, `fork()` ... A lot of forking and `setsid`, very likely to ensure detachment from tty.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why the parent is detached as well.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I could successfully track down the problem.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rhpk/861e5970044d7ade997a) for a working code example (replace `/dev/pts/17` with the output of the `tty` command).

The problem is related to the following step in `sysvinit`'s `spawn()` function:

```
(void)ioctl(f, TIOCSCTTY, 1);
```

`ioctl()` is actually stealing the controlling tty `/dev/console` which, in my case, is a bind mount of the `pty` of the current process.